# Cant connect via SSH or XRDP over wireguard

Tags: networking, openssh, raspbian, wireguard, xrdp

I have a wireguard server and 2 wireguard peers connected to the server.  All 3 can ping each other on the wg0 interface, but the 2 peers cannot connect to each other.

I have found where people had similar issues and it was an issue where packets were getting shredded due to MTU.  Ive lowered the MTU to 1280 on both peers and the issue persists.

Peer A is a windows computer trying to connect to Peer B through Server C.

Peer A can ping Peer B.  I have confirmed Peer B is working by SSHing, RDPing, and loading its apache2 test site from computers on its local network so i dont think its a firewall issue.

Peer A (windows desktop) wireguard config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PRIVATEKEY=
Address = 192.168.3.2/24
DNS = 192.168.1.2
MTU = 1280
[Peer]
PublicKey = PUBLICKEY=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.3.0/24, 10.1.1.0/24
Endpoint = CONNECTIONLOCATION:PORT
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Peer B's config (RASPBIANPI)

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.3.231/24
PrivateKey = PRIVATEKEY=
MTU = 1280
DNS = 8.8.8.8
[Peer]
PublicKey = PUBLICKEY=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.3.0/24
Endpoint = CONNECTION:PORT
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

My best guess is the Wireguard server is setup and routing correctly since both peers can ping the server and each other on their wireguard interfaces.

Peer B is giving timeout errors when trying to SSH into it so its like either SSH connection isnt making it to it or the wg0 interface just isnt listening to that port.